# mod_rewrite not passing query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with mod_rewrite.

here is my .htaccess file:

```
#REWRITE
RewriteEngine On    #Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/?$ admin.php?kappa=$1 [NC,L,QSA] # Handle Admin Panel
RewriteRule ^buypoint/([0-9]+)/?$ baltopoints.php?sid=$1 [NC,L] # Handle bit->Point requests
RewriteRule ^history/([0-9]+)?/?$ history.php?page=$1 [NC,L] # Handle Transaction requests
RewriteRule ^topupstatus/(.*)/?$ topupsta.php?ec=$1 [NC,L] # Handle index
RewriteRule ^refresh/(.*)?$ refresh.php [NC,L] # Handle Refresh requests
RewriteRule ^refill/(.*)?$ topup.php [NC,L] # Refill
RewriteRule ^topup/(.*)?$ topup.php [NC,L] # Refill
RewriteRule ^ucp/?(.*)?$ main.php [NC,L] # Handle index
RewriteRule ^logout/?(.*)?$ logout.php [NC,L] # Handle Logout
```

the rewrite only work for rule:
**^buypoint/([0-9]+)/?$ baltopoints.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]** rule
( buypoint/1 *will rewrite to* baltopoints.php?sid=1 )
otherwise, only work for first slashes 
(admin/viewbtx *will rewrite to* admin.php  *[with no query string]*)

Can someone help me about this problem?

Comment: At first glance, nothing seems wrong with these rules. Are you running any framework or do you have any rules in httpd.conf? If you get a 404-error, please note that the query string will usually not be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by renaming  `admin.php` to `admincp.php` and use 
`RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admincp.php?do=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`
rule instead of the one in question so i think it's apache bug or something

Answer (score 0):

The rule matches the regexp against the URi *less* the query string.  A `?` in the pattern makes the previous atom optional.  This is std regexp syntax so `^a.php?e=$1$` will match `a.phe=23` for example.  You parse the query string using `RewriteCond` statement preceding the `RewriteRule`, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^ec=(\d+)
```

and now `%1` index number is available to the rules replacement string.  Read up the examples in [Apache Module mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: I am officially confused by this answer. Reading the question a few times, I think the input is `admin/viewbtx`. There is no query string to match there. He says that he does an internal rewrite to `admin.php?kappa=viewbtx`, but somehow that doesn't work. There is no need to match a query string.

Comment: LoL.  You are right.  I completely misread the rules. -- that's why I always column-align mine -- It's mind-fart.  I'd delete the A but you wouldn't get this resp.  But there's no way that `admin/viewbtx` rewrites to `admin.php` with no query string, unless other rules are firing in this or other `.htaccess`

Comment: Yes, i was intended to rewrite `admin/viewbtx` to `admin.php?kappa=viewbtx` but ended up apache rewrite to `admin.php` instead

Comment: @NutInta, (1) Are there any other rules in your `.htaccess` not listed above; (2) or other `.htaccess` or system / vhost rewrite rules firing. If you have root access to your Apache config, then try turning on rewrite debug logging and follow through what is happening here, because something strange is.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer I gave to another question, it may be useful to you

[How to htaccess redirect this long URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047745/how-to-htaccess-redirect-this-long-url/20047865#20047865)