# How to htaccess redirect this long URL?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get my script working. How to redirect and customize the below URL?

```
https://example.com/order?send=value1&send2=value2&send3=value3
```

to

```
https://example.com/order/value1/value2/value3
```

Comment: _What have you tried so far?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(order)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1?send=$2&send2=$3&send3=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

this site can help you: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /order?send=$1&send2=$2&send3=$3 [L]
```