# Removing .php file extension from URL meant to be used with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I am making a tiny app, which will have a small AJAX submission URL. It is made in PHP, and the URL is `blah/ajax/submit.php`. I would like the route to be `blah/ajax/submit`, without the php file extension. I could not figure this out using htaccess, nor by deleting the php extension, or renaming `submit.php` to `index.php` and placing it in the `blah/ajax/submit` directory. Is there a way to do what I am asking for without some big library or framework? I intend to use Laravel or Django in the future, but for now, I need a solution that can be up and running in minutes.

Comment: thats what mod rewrite is for http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: see this my answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047745/how-to-htaccess-redirect-this-long-url/20047865#20047865

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you call `/ajax/submit` then add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^/ajax/submit$ /ajax/submit.php [L]
```

Or alternatively, add this to the htaccess file in the `/ajax/` directory:

```
RewriteBase /ajax/
RewriteRule ^submit$ submit.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way... Let us know if it works!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.*$ ./submit.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./submit.php
```

Save this as `.htaccess` and put it inside `/ajax/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept having different kind of errors and problems with the solutions proposed, but I found a way to solve my problem by using a minimalist router:

http://toroweb.org/

Thanks to everyone for teaching me about .htaccess